# how to fix the "Component definition is missing display name" error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    const IndeterminateCheckbox = React.forwardRef(
  
    ({indeterminate, ...rest}, ref) => {
      const defaultRef = React.useRef();
      const resolvedRef = ref || defaultRef;

      React.useEffect(() => {
        resolvedRef.current.indeterminate = indeterminate;
      }, [resolvedRef, indeterminate]);

      return <input type="checkbox" ref={resolvedRef} {...rest} />;
    },
);
```

How to fix "Component definition is missing display name" in line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this error, you should put a `displayName` on your component. This happens because your `arrow function inside forwardRef` doesn't have the context of your `function name`.

`Solution one`:

Put this on the final of your file.

```
    const IndeterminateCheckbox = React.forwardRef(
     ({indeterminate, ...rest}, ref) => {
      const defaultRef = React.useRef();
      const resolvedRef = ref || defaultRef;

      React.useEffect(() => {
        resolvedRef.current.indeterminate = indeterminate;
      }, [resolvedRef, indeterminate]);

      return <input type="checkbox" ref={resolvedRef} {...rest} />;
    },
);

IndeterminateCheckbox.displayName = 'IndeterminateCheckbox'
```

OR

You can avoid use `arrow function inside forwardRef` and `use named functions`.

```
    const IndeterminateCheckbox = React.forwardRef(
     function Component({indeterminate, ...rest}, ref) {
      const defaultRef = React.useRef();
      const resolvedRef = ref || defaultRef;

      React.useEffect(() => {
        resolvedRef.current.indeterminate = indeterminate;
      }, [resolvedRef, indeterminate]);

      return <input type="checkbox" ref={resolvedRef} {...rest} />;
    }
  },
);
```